# Issues with number of threads with openMP in C

Tags: c, openmp

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    omp_set_dynamic(0);
    omp_set_num_threads(4);

    #pragma omp paralell
    {
        printf("%d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }

}
```

The output:

```
0
```

Shouldn't the output be some permutation of 0, 1, 2, and 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing `omp_set_dynamic(0);` you indicate that the runtime will not dynamically adjust the number of threads. The argument of this function should be nonzero to avail the dynamic adjustment of num. of threads. Also you misspelled `parallel` in the code.

Comment: omp_set_dynamic(0) was intentional, misspelling parallel, however, was not. The code works with correct English :)

Answer (score 1):

If you copy & pasted your source code, I think its because "parallel" is spelled wrong. 
I just found out that gcc **silently ignores** mispelling for openmp pragmas if the -W flag is not set. Compiling with -Wall gives

```
warning: ignoring #pragma omp paralell [-Wunknown-pragmas]
#pragma omp paralell
```

It is therefore a good idea to let gcc print warnings.

Answer (score 0):

And don't forget the enable OpenMP support of the compiler, which is disabled by default for mainstream compilers like gcc/icc/vc++